# Correct XML to send for cache web service SOAP header

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I created a simple header class:

```
Class Sample.Headers Extends %SOAP.Header
{
    Parameter NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
    Property UserName As %String;
}
```

In the web service I made sure to set the correct namespace in the `SOAPHEADERS` parameter:

```
Parameter SOAPHEADERS = "UserName:Sample.Headers";
```

I send the following XML using SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <tem:UserName>This is the header</tem:UserName>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Test>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:argAge>10</tem:argAge>
      </tem:Test>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR #6254: Tag expected, XML input, This is the header, is not in
>   proper format as child of UserName (ending at line 3 character 18).

What is the correct format for the XML so that UserName is set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change:

```
Property UserName As %String;
```

to

```
Property UserName As %String(XMLPROJECTION = "CONTENT", MAXLEN = 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the example here: http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_header.asp

> **Note**: All immediate child elements of the Header element must be namespace-qualified.

It seems like the format of the XML is a bit different in this example, nesting a namespace as an attribute of the Header property "Trans" (in their example).  It might be a stretch, but I do see that your request doesn't have the namespace explicitly set like this.

Comment: I tried their example with the namespace and I still get the same result.